# Importing non-module external javascript libraries in Angular 2/5

Tags: javascript, angular

I've googled this question over & over again but I couldn't find actual solution.

Is there a way to get external javascript librarie(s) in Angular 2/5?

The javascript library is like

```
<script src="http://developers.kakao.com/sdk/js/kakao.min.js"></script>
```

(which can't be implemented in Angular component.ts)

I've tried:

```
declare let Kakao: any;

Kakao.import('http://developers.kakao.com/sdk/js/kakao.min.js');
```

but this not works wherever this code is in *.component.ts or *.d.ts, whatever.

```
import * as Kakao from 'http://developers.kakao.com/sdk/js/kakao.min.js';
```

This didn't work just like the first code.

I've also tried:

```
constructor() {
    this.loadAPI = new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.loadScript();
    resolve(true);
  });
}

public loadScript() {
let isFound = false;
const scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
for (let i = 0; i < scripts.length; ++i) {
  if (scripts[i].getAttribute('src') != null && 
    scripts[i].getAttribute('src').includes('loader')) {
    isFound = true;
  }
}

if (!isFound) {
  const dynamicScripts = ['http://developers.kakao.com/sdk/js/kakao.min.js'];

  for (let i = 0; i < dynamicScripts.length; i++) {
    const node = document.createElement('script');
    node.src = dynamicScripts[i];
    node.type = 'text/javascript';
    node.async = false;
    node.charset = 'utf-8';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
  }
}
```

This works, but I believe this solution can't get Object from the library 'Kakao'.

In other words, I need to call the codes after loaded:

```
Kakao.init('some_string');
function() { Kakao.doSomething(); }
```

please help!

Comment: Why don't you just have the script tag part of the index.html and **declare const Kakao;** in your component?

Comment: @GSSwain I tried, but when trying, it says "ERROR ReferenceError: Kakao is not defined"

Comment: Can you add your index.html code here also